# If you have 2 extensions in Visual Studio that do the same thing, what happens?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of extensions installed in Visual Studio 2010 (via the extension manager) for enhancing how VS treats javascript files.

Each of the extensions provide specific features that I require, however....

Some of the extensions have overlapping features e.g. the "JScript Editor Extensions" oack and "JSEnhancements" both provide "outlining support for javascript".

Does one extension overrule the other extension? Or what happens in the background - are the extensions actually battling each other and trying to do the same thing? Or does the latest installed plugin overrule?

-thanks for the help